# How to query table based on option value selected?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

How do I hide 'role' selection option until 'project' is selected and then query role where project selected = $project?

I only want to select a role corresponding to its project.  The table selectproject contains a row with $id_project, $project and $role.  I would like to select the role based on first selecting a project.  Ex: "select $role where selected = $project".

How do I use Java script or Ajax to accomplish this?  Please provide code for I am still learning Java/Ajax.

```
<?php

$result4= mysqli_query($con, $idq);


echo '<select id="project" name="project" class="textBox">';
echo '<option value="">-Select-</option>';
while ($row = $result4->fetch_assoc()){

?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['project']; ?>"><?php echo $row['project']; ?></option>
<?php    
}
echo "</select>";

?>

<?php


$result5= mysqli_query($con, $idq2);


echo '<select id="role" name="role" class="textBox2">';
echo '<option value="">-Select-</option>';
while ($row = $result5->fetch_assoc()){


?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['role']; ?>"><?php echo $row['role']; ?></option>
<?php    
}
echo "</select>";


?>
```

Comment: Use ajax/jquery to load the 2nd list of options based on what was selected from the first option, or preload the available option and its connections so you can use simple javascript to manipulate the options.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. So you want to have your second list hidden until an item from the first is selected? If this is the case you need JavaScript. If you want to dynamically reload the second list after an element is clicked you will need AJAX.

Comment: That is correct.  I will need Java script or ajax/jquery to hide the second list until an item from the first list is selected.  I haven't found any good examples yet.

Comment: I think you would do well to read a tutorial on AJAX in general which would help you understand how to program this. But from a more practical standpoint, you may also want to consider this plugin which could do it for you: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained.